# Getting java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException in List

Tags: java

I am getting

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

exception in List.

Why does this exception occur?

#### Code

```
List<String> smsUserList = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (event.getEventTemplate().equalsIgnoreCase(CommunicationConstants.MEMBER)) {
        String testNumbers = env.getRequiredProperty(CommunicationConstants.TEST_SMS_NUMBRES);
        String[] testSmsNumber = testNumbers.split(",");
        if (null != testSmsNumber && testSmsNumber.length > 1) {
            smsUserList = Arrays.asList(testSmsNumber);

        }

    }
    if (event.getEventTemplate().equalsIgnoreCase(CommunicationConstants.AGENT)) {
        String testNumbers = env.getRequiredProperty(CommunicationConstants.TEST_SMS_NUMBRES);
        String[] testSmsNumber = testNumbers.split(",");
        if (null != testSmsNumber && testSmsNumber.length > 1) {
            smsUserList = Arrays.asList(testSmsNumber);
        }
    }

    Set<SMSCommunicationRecipient> smsRecipientAll = event.getSmsCommunicationRecipient();
    for (SMSCommunicationRecipient smsRecipient : smsRecipientAll) {
        String smsRecipientValue = smsRecipient.getRecipientGroupId().getReferenceTypeValue();
        if (smsRecipientValue.equalsIgnoreCase(CommunicationConstants.MEMBER)) {
            List<String> memberContact = (List<String>) communicationInput
                    .get(CommunicationConstants.MEMBER_CONTACT_NUMBER_LIST);
            if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(memberContact)) {
                for (String smsNumber : memberContact) {
                    smsUserList.add(smsNumber);
                }
            }
        }
        if (smsRecipientValue.equalsIgnoreCase(CommunicationConstants.AGENT)) {
            List<String> agentContact = (List<String>) communicationInput
                    .get(CommunicationConstants.AGENT_CONTACT_NUMBER_LIST);
            if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(agentContact)) {
                for (String smsNumber : agentContact) {
                    smsUserList.add(smsNumber);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: May I know, from which line you are getting this .?

Answer (score 3):

`Arrays.asList(testSmsNumber)` returns a fixed sized list, so you cannot add elements to it.

Change

```
smsUserList = Arrays.asList(testSmsNumber);
```

to

```
smsUserList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(testSmsNumber));
```

Or, since you are already creating an `ArrayList` with:

```
List<String> smsUserList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

change

```
smsUserList = Arrays.asList(testSmsNumber);
```

to

```
smsUserList.addAll(Arrays.asList(testSmsNumber));
```

Though if you take this second approach, depending on your logic, you might want to call `smsUserList.clear()` before `smsUserList.addAll()` (since there are multiple places in your code that assign to the `smsUserList` variable, so perhaps you want the `List` to be cleared each time you make that assignment).